# Automatically vscode creates parentheses when the parameter of the arrow function is only one. How to fix up this?

Tags: autocomplete, eslint, parentheses, eslint-config-airbnb

If I supply arrow function with an argument like:

```
  const onClickBtn = e => { 
    handleSearch();
  };
```

vs code add parentheses like:

```
  const onClickBtn = (e) => { 
    handleSearch();
  };
```

I don't want the setting to be like this.

I thought this was a eslint settings problem, so I googled but couldn't find an answer.

How can I fix up this problems?

Answer (score 2):

[ESLint Arrow Parenthesis](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens) ESLint defines this as good practice, although I specifically don't like this behaviour. You will need to change the corresponding setting to `"as-needed"` which will no longer enforce braces around the arrow function parameters.

Comment:  First Thanks for your  reply!!

The solution I found is to change the settings in vs code!! ,and it was a matter of Prettier.
At vs code settings, I changed the setting value of "Prettier: Arrow Parens" to "avoid".

If you ever have the same problem, try this!! Thx ^^

Comment: No problem I'm glad you could find a solution. I recommend that you mention Prettier in your question so readers have a better understanding as I assumed you just used ESLint.